# Android SQLit Search: NullPointerException?

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-cursor

I need to perform a search operation into my SQLite DB.

In my Activity, I have `EditText` for entering the keyword and a search `Button`. Once the user clicks the button, the EditText text will be stored in the `keyword` and sent to a `search(String keyword)` method in the DBHelper class.

I have this code in my `SearchActivity`for `onCreate()` and `onClick()`:

```
//SearchActivity class extends ListActivity and implements OnClickListener 
Button search;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter ca;
ListView lv;
EditText txt;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_term);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);

    search.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {}

    try {
    String keyword= txt.getText().toString();
    Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.search(keyword); //A method in my DB
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] columns = {cursor.getColumnName(1)}; 
    int[] columnsLayouts = {R.id.item_title};
    ca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getBaseContext(), R.layout.items_layout, cursor,columns , columnsLayouts);
    lv = getListView();
    lv.setAdapter(ca);

    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

However, I got `NullPointerException` in the LogCat!! I couldn't find where the error is.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: provide the logcat information and which line you got that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description to the NullPointerException could be a little more informative. But it is very likely that the NullPointerException occurs here:

```
1: Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.search(keyword); //A method in my DB
2: cursor.moveToFirst();
3: String[] columns = {cursor.getColumnName(1)};
```

or here:

```
1: try {
2:    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
3: } catch (SQLException sqle) {}
```

Either in the first part in line 1: or 2: or in the second part in line 2:

You should always check if objects which rely on the existence of data are `not null`. So you should check if `cursor` is `null`. Another thing could be that you never initialize `myDbHelper`.

Comment: It was the other thing. I didn't know how I forget to initialize the DBHelper variable !! And I don't know how did you catch it !! Thanks man :-)